# How to iterate through package.json files of global and local npm packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to look through the package.json files of all packages installed globally and locally via npm, but not sure how to do it globally?

I know `process.execPath` will get me the directory to the globally installed exectuables, but not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is use the NPM api. First 'npm link npm' in your project. Then you can call the NPM object to enumerate modules. For example:

```
var npm = require('npm');
npm.load({}, function(err, npm) {
  npm.config.set("global", true);
  npm.commands.list([], true, function(err, pkgInfo) {
    console.log(pkgInfo);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, however I don't know how to mute the stdout to the console (I don't want to see the entire tree get outputted).  I've tried `npm.config.set("loglevel", "silent");` but that only mutes everything else.  Any clues?

Comment: OK, I edited the code so that it won't show the tree (the 'true' second param).

Comment: @NickJonas now (in 2017) it seems muted, but if you still have the problem, you could run it in a child process and then send the console logging that you *do* want with a separate stream, like fs.createWriteStream.